# Google Workspace Calendar Iframe Name

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, embedding

I'm embeding some Google Workspace Calendars to my website. When I click to the change calendar box, some names display as email, some have just names,... it's messy.

Have you got any idea how to deal with this?

[Messy calendar names :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMEzh.jpg)

I tried to change the names of the calendars in settings of the calendar, but even though I'm the owner and the name is changed, it doesn't apply to the . I tried to make calendar public in settings, but the result was still the same.